# ellipsis not working on bootstrap with flex

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I am trying to add ellipsis after 2 lines of icons, the HTML is below. I tried various combinations by going through many pages. Like changing min-width to 0 and others. All the efforts seem to be useless by now. Hence I turned out for some expert eyes on this, please have a look

```
.ellipsis {
            display: -webkit-box;
            -webkit-line-clamp: 4;
            -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
        }



.gicon{
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            background-position: center center;
            background-size: auto 100%;
            height: 32px;
            width: 32px;
            align-self: center;
        }

    <div class="row facilityRow">
                                        <div class="col d-flex align-content-start flex-wrap ellipsis">
                                            <div class="d-flex flex-column mr-3">
                                                <i class="gicon" path="001-meditation" rel="tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Mediation"></i>
                                                <small>Mediation</small>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="d-flex flex-column mr-3">
                                                <i class="gicon" path="003-yoga" rel="tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Yoga"></i>
                                                <small>Yoga</small>
                                            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unable to see it the way you're seeing it. If you're using an external icon library, could you include the link? Or if they are custom icons, then a picture of what you're seeing as well as an example of what behaviour you're expecting

Comment: Desipte the fact that you are 8 years on stackoverflow,  you can not even bother to format your code.  I think if you do so and include the library you use, you may get many more answers.

Comment: @mahan why are you so concerned about my years on StackOverflow? that sounds funny lol. BTW I copied the code from the editor, and here I applied the code tag.

Answer (score 0):

At first, don't use `small`. Use an element that does not format text, for example, `p`.

You need to **restirct its immediate parent's width**. If  there is **enough space on the x-axis**, it does not work.

```css
.ellipsis {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 32px;
}

.ellipsis p {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="row facilityRow">
  <div class="col d-flex align-content-start flex-wrap">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column mr-3">
      <i class="gicon" path="001-meditation" rel="tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Mediation"></i>
      <div class="ellipsis">
        <p>Mediation</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex  mr-3">
      <i class="gicon" path="003-yoga" rel="tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Yoga"></i>
      <div class="ellipsis">
        <p>Yoga</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try. I fixed in someother way

Comment: @Aadam Could you post your solution? Someone may find it helpful.